# Call a PostgreSQL function and get result back with no loop

Tags: postgresql, rust

I have a simple rust program that interacts with a PostgreSQL database.

The actual code is:

```
for row in &db_client.query("select magic_value from priv.magic_value();", &[]).unwrap()
{
    magic_value = row.get("magic_value");
    println!("Magic value is = {}", magic_value);
}
```

And.. it works. But I don't like it: I know this function will return one and only one value.

From the example I found, for example here: https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/index.html
and here: https://tms-dev-blog.com/postgresql-database-with-rust-how-to/

You always have a recordset to loop on.

Which is the clean way to call a function without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` returns a `Result<Vec<Row>, _>`. You are already unwrapping the `Vec`, so you can just use it directly instead of looping.  By turning the `Vec` into an owning iterator yourself, you can even easily obtain a `Row` instead of a `&Row`.

```
magic_value = db_client.query("select magic_value from priv.magic_value();", &[])
    .unwrap()    // -> Vec<Row>
    .into_iter() // -> impl Iterator<Item=Row>
    .next()      // -> Option<Row>
    .unwrap()    // -> Row
    .get("magic_value");
```